# How to get json data via requests

Tags: json, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

The current code I am trying to write is to identify whether or not a person's most recent crypto transaction was either them receiving the money or sending the money and if they sent the money how much.

The current code I have written is

```
def getRecentTransactionInfo(cryptoabbr, address):

    url = f"https://{cryptoabbr}.tokenview.io/en/address/{address}"
    html_text = requests.get(url).text

    inp, out = re.search(r'value:"([^"]+).*?value:"([^"]+)', html_text).groups()
    print(inp) # This prints the amount sent to the wallet if they were the output
```

This prints how much was sent and received in the transaction but does not say by who it just has the values. I haven't been able to find a way to retrieve the data.

The link I've been using to test is: "https://ltc.tokenview.io/en/address/M8T1B2Z97gVdvmfkQcAtYbEepune1tzGua"

The input on the website is how much was sent the output is how much was received. I'm not sure where I can locate the data but I believe it is in the json that I used to get the input output amount.

Answer (score 0):

To get first transaction you can use for example [`js2py`](https://pypi.org/project/Js2Py/) to parse the javascript data embedded inside the page:

```py
import re

import js2py
import requests


def getRecentTransactionInfo(cryptoabbr, address):
    url = f"https://{cryptoabbr}.tokenview.io/en/address/{address}"
    html_text = requests.get(url).text

    js_func = re.search(r"window\.__NUXT__=(\(.*?\)\);)", html_text).group(1)

    data = js2py.eval_js(js_func)

    # return first transaction:
    return data["data"][1]["sourceData"][0]["txs"][0]


print(getRecentTransactionInfo("ltc", "M8T1B2Z97gVdvmfkQcAtYbEepune1tzGua"))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "block_no": 2607927,
    "confirmations": 4359,
    "fee": "0.0000113",
    "height": 2607927,
    "index": 800,
    "inputCnt": 1,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "address": "LaMKADY7ozZXt7BuLogijtwJzNEXy42fGv",
            "input_no": 0,
            "received_from": {
                "output_no": 1,
                "txid": "b1efc2174229b547e2c44e1823ccbb18252d2ad9ab7296ba52e5093f18d6e211",
            },
            "value": "0.02387814",
        }
    ],
    "network": "LTC",
    "outputCnt": 2,
    "outputs": [
        {
            "address": "LaMKADY7ozZXt7BuLogijtwJzNEXy42fGv",
            "output_no": 0,
            "value": "0.02319739",
        },
        {
            "address": "M8T1B2Z97gVdvmfkQcAtYbEepune1tzGua",
            "output_no": 1,
            "value": "0.00066945",
        },
    ],
    "time": 1704176352,
    "txid": "3cad38d66fdb1a40f20c82f0f55211a75bd8720bc2c71a286af32170f56eae9b",
    "type": "tx",
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response but this script returns a keyerror: 3 for me. Is there a reason why this may be happening?